# Visual Studio 2010 slow debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with vs2010, when i start debugging it works slow. Internet explorer opens but website loads extremely slowly. I stopped my anti-virus program but it couldn't be resolved. My workmate and me work on the same project and he doesn't have any problem like that. My hardware is 4G memory + Intel Core i5 CPU 3.20 GHz.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I have tried disabling IntelliTrace, and disabling other debugging options, but it is still really slow. It only became super slow during the past couple weeks. I can't upgrade RAM or anything with my computer because it's a work computer so I don't know what else I can do. I have even installed PerfWatson, but so far it hasn't done anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try disabling IntelliTrace, it could be adding quite a bit of overhead.

Go to *Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace* and uncheck the *Enable IntelliTrace* checkbox, or obviously, you could also fine tune it to improve its performance to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did a winupdate(20120508) and Visual studio seemed to be really slow debugging afterwards
with a 1 minute delay after compile-to-runDebug lag, then when the debug program exited, another 1 minute delay to 
get control again of visual studio. I did clean all, but no joy.

Solution: I manually deleted the *.sdf and *.suo files in my project/solution and rebuilt. Issue went away magically.

Not sure why, but something was out of sync, corrupted, or incompatible with the update and needed to be blown away manually.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you are running AV but if I might ask what AV program?

Our department had ran Symantec for years and were constantly getting infected with spyware without alerts from our AV.  We switched over to Comodo AV and found that Symantec was missing quite a bit.

You might try scanning with Comodo and see if there are other spyware or malware issues on your workstation that's not getting picked up by your current antivirus.

Just a thought.